# Highcharts add ticks after chart was rendered

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with some data. My tick calculation however needs some time so what I'd like to do is render the chart and show it to the user, calculate ticks in the background and once done add the ticks to the chart without rerender it.

Is that possible somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally ticks cannot be render "after" points drawing, because engine calculate ticks based on points, and render them.

Comment: That's not right. Ticks are calculated based on axis extremes and some option like tickIntervall. But you can always (and I do) have your own tickPositioner method that returns an array of tick positions that could even be random.